# SonarQube server [http://localhost:9001] can not be reached (Already check all the previous Q. on stackoverflow)

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis, sonar-runner

**I am getting below error after running command sonar-scanner. My scanner version is sonar-scanner-2.6.1, sonarqube version is sonarqube5.4, java version "1.8.0_161",Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
,Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)**

### I have also try with other ports like 9001, 9002 but it is still not workig.

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner-2.6.1/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
    INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/parth-favcy/favcy/favcy/value-x/sonar-project.properties
    INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1
    INFO: Java 1.8.0_161 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
    INFO: Linux 4.13.0-36-generic amd64
    INFO: User cache: /home/parth-favcy/.sonar/cache
    ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9001] can not be reached
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INFO: Total time: 0.373s
    INFO: Final Memory: 3M/119M
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
    ERROR: Unable to execute SonarQube
    ERROR: Caused by: Fail to download libraries from server
    ERROR: Caused by: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    ERROR: 
    ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Scanner with the -e switch.
    ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    parth-favcy@parthfavcy-HP-Notebook:~/favcy/favcy/value-x$ /opt/sonar-scanner-2.6.1/bin/sonar-scanner -X
    INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner-2.6.1/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
    INFO: Project root configuration file: /home/parth-favcy/favcy/favcy/value-x/sonar-project.properties
    INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1
    INFO: Java 1.8.0_161 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
    INFO: Linux 4.13.0-36-generic amd64
    INFO: User cache: /home/parth-favcy/.sonar/cache
    DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
    DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
    DEBUG: Download: http://localhost:9001/batch_bootstrap/index
    ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9001] can not be reached
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    INFO: Total time: 0.341s
    INFO: Final Memory: 3M/119M
    INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
    org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:70)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:60)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:93)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
            ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
            at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
            at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:101)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:198)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:358)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:117)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:276)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:114)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:99)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:78)
            ... 11 more


    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    My iptable rule : 
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain DOCKER (0 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (0 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain DOCKER-USER (0 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination  
    ---------------------------------------------------------

    Sonar Properties file :
#Configure here general information about the environment, such as SonarQube DB details for example
#No information about specific project should appear here

#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9001

#----- Default source code encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#----- Global database settings (not used for SonarQube 5.2+)
#sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
#sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- PostgreSQL
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar

#----- MySQL
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

#----- Oracle
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE

#----- Microsoft SQLServer
#sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/sonar;SelectMethod=Cursor
```

---

sonar.properties file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dc1sj0_lcGpQ41NoFmRZH593ww-4Bf_F

Comment: I have check http://localhost:9000 and  http://localhost:9001 on browser to but I am not able to access that too.

Comment: Can you post the `sonar.properties` file of your *server* ? You seems to have Docker installed, did you use SonarQube inside Docker, in this case did you add `-p 9001:9001` flag ?

Comment: sonar-scanner properties file is already mentioned in question. Also I have tried without docker too but I am still getting same error

Comment: I've asked for the _server_ configuration file not the scanner configuration file! Your first step should be to be able to connect to SonarQube with a brower.

Comment: Shared sonar.properties file too. I haven't change anything in that  file